# Using WMTS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wmts

I would like to import the data published as a WMTS by the City of Vienna (http://data.wien.gv.at/) as a layer in QGIS.

Is this possible, and if yes, how do I do it?

This is what I am talking about:

> http://data.wien.gv.at/formate/geowebservices.html

I could successfully load the WMS service, but I could not do the same with WMTS.

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS 2.2.0 you can use the *Add WMS/WMTS Layer* menu option directly; then when you create a new connection you need to supply the url to the WMTS capabilities document.

When you connect to your WMTS, you then select the Tilesets tab option and select the layer you want to use.

[image: Selecting the WMTS layer from the Tilesets list in QGIS 2.2.0]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it could be possible if you modify the existing [OpenLayers Plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/) for QGIS to do this

You can get the source code for it at github to get an editable version: https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin

You don't have to fork or clone with git account, they offer the [source code in a zip/tarball](https://github.com/sourcepole/qgis-openlayers-plugin/archive/master.zip) for anyone to download.

You can see some instructions on how to add your own entry at the[project wiki](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/openlayers/wiki) for this plugin:

- *Add a HTML file with your layer in html/*
- *Register your layer in the __init__ method of class OpenlayersPlugin (openlayers_plugin.py)*

It looks like this plugin was used to make a new plugin recently added: [TMS for Korean Users](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/tmsforkorea/) so mod away =)

And according to the [GetCapabilities document of the WMTS](http://data.wien.gv.at/daten/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml) you've pointed to, they offer the service in the Google Mercator projection so it should fit nicely without having to modify any SRS parameters in the OpenLayers plugin.